# How can I solve this Excel Visual Basic run-time error '62'?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have created a Visual Basic script in Excel to open, grab contents and close a number (more than one hundred) of Word documents.

Part of the code is:

```
Private Function GrabTextFile(ByVal file_name As String) As String
Dim fnum As Long
    fnum = FreeFile()
    Open file_name For Input As #fnum
    GrabTextFile = Input$(LOF(fnum), #fnum)
    Close #fnum
End Function
```

(The rest of the code is heavily based on [this page from VB helper](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_list_doc_words.html).)

The script fails on line:

```
GrabTextFile = Input$(LOF(fnum), #fnum)
```

with the message:

```
Run-time error '62':

Input past end of file
```

It fails on document 34. However, if I remove *that specific document* and then rerun the script, it fails on the new document at that location. This implies to me that I have a problem freeing some memory(?).

Comment: That code looks fine. 99% of the time you will see this error when you attempt read with `For Input` when the file is actually binary or contains dbcs characters, try `strconv(InputB(LOF(fnum), #fnum), vbUnicode)`

Comment: @AlexK. thanks, but when I try that Excel crashes!

Comment: Can you rename the files so that the current document #34 moves up to position #33 and the current #33 goes to #34? This will tell you if you have an issue with the specific document or an issue with exhausting some resource

Comment: If the files are really Word files, why not use the ``GrabWordFile`` function from that VB Helper page?

Comment: @barrowc: I did something similar, I removed all the documents except #34. It still failed on #34, so it is likely related to a property of that document (and #35).

Comment: @RachelHettinger: that's it, thanks! The documents were of **.docx** format, so they the GrabTextFile method was selected (since, in the linked code, the method searches only for **.doc**. When I add "Or .docx", it works (GrabWordFile is used). If you put this into an answer format, I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are Word documents, I suggest you try the `GrabWordFile` function instead of the `GrabTextFile` function listed on that [VB Helper page](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_list_doc_words.html).

Comment: This was necessary because the documents that did not work used the new .docx extension instead of simply .doc. Once I built in an Or .docx code into the If .doc Then GrabWordFile code, it worked fine.